# cakephp - add detail to static user object

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp 2.5.4, with `$this->Auth->user()` I can access to user object

I want when user logged in, set some user detail in user object and with `$this->Auth->user()` function, get all info in all controller

```
  $user = $this->Auth->user();      

  $this->loadModel('Resource');      
  $resource = $this->Resource->find('threaded', array('order' => 'index'));
  // here, i want add $resource to user object
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, untested but should work.

```
$this->Session->write($this->Auth->sessionKey, array_merge(
    $resource,
    $this->Auth->user()
));
```

It is unlikely that the session key changes in most apps but it can happen. I don't consider it as good practice to hardcode the key everywhere like most people do.

Also keep in mind that this *won't* work with state less authentication systems!

You can also contain additional data when configuring the Auth adapters. [Read this section of the manual.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) Taken from the manual and added the contain:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'contain' => array('Foo', 'Bar')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, just i use AuthComponent::$sessionKey instead of $this->Auth->sessionKey

Comment: Calling statics and singletons is (most of the time) bad practice as well. You can't mock it this way, you can't change the class this way easily but need to do a search and replace the best. Dealing with object instances that you can inject is much better.